# Androidでタップしたアイコンが大きく前面に出るようにするには

Tags: android

AndroidTVでは選択しているアイコンが大きくなり前面に出ています。

スマートフォンのAndroidアプリでも同様の効果を見せたいと思っています。
・タップでアイコンが前面に出て大きくなります。
・他のアイコンはサイズもそのまま

LinearLayoutでアイコンを並べると、タップしたアイコンは大きくなりますが他のアイコンはズレます。
簡単にこの効果を出すにはどのようにプログラムすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

そういった場合、ScaleAnimationで大きさを制御すれば、レイアウトへの影響がなくなります。
例えば、タップ時に大きさを変える場合は、以下のようなコーディングをすれば良いかと思います（あくまでご参考までに）。

```
public void onClickImage(View v) {
    // 押下時の処理
    final ImageView image = (ImageView)v;
    image.setScaleX(1.0f);
    image.setScaleY(1.0f);
    ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 2.5f, 1.0f, 2.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    animation.setDuration(300);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    image.startAnimation(animation);
}
```